# Why isn't hovering in css/html allowing me to change the styling of another div?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to hover over the I9ScanningRequestForm div to change the background color of the FormPreviewPane div from purple to white. In my Sharepoint 2010 web page, however, this hovering event seems to be ignored. Is there something wrong with my code? How can I control the color of one div by hovering over another div?

```
<style>

.opaqueBlock{
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
opacity:0.5;
margin-left: 60px; 
width: 360px; 
height: 35px; 
background-color: #3D5567;
}

.opaqueBlock:hover{
border: 1px dotted #304A63;
}

.formLinkContainer{ 
width:430px; 
height:37px;
position: absolute;
}


.formLinkContainer:hover { 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
opacity: 0.4;
}


 #I9ScanningRequestForm:hover ~ #FormPreviewPane {
 background-color: white;
}


.formTextSpan{
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; margin-left: 70px; 
color: white; 
margin-top: 1px; 
font-family: 'Didact Gothic' !important; 
font-size: 22px !important;
}

.formIcon{
height: 34px;
position: absolute; 
margin-left:13px;
}

 img{border: none;}

 </style>

 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact Gothic' rel='stylesheet'>




<div style="background-image: url('/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/WoodBackgroundMedium.jpg') !important; height: 1300px;">


<br/>


<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Archiving_Cover_Sheet_Ease.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 180px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Archiving Cover Sheet</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>


<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/ARCHIVING%20SHEET.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 220px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
 <span class="formTextSpan">Archiving Sheet</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Data%20Entry%20Feedback.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 260px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Data Entry Feedback Form</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Data_Entry_Comm_Form_10.28.24.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 300px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Data Entry - Commercials</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Data_Entry_Form.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 340px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Data Entry Assistance Request</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/DataPackageRemake.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 380px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Data Package Remake</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/emp_Receivable.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 420px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Employee Receivable Request Form</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Filing_Cover_Sheet_v2.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 460px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Filing Cover Sheet</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/FedEx_UPS_Billing.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 500px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">FedEx/UPS Billing Form</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Forgery_Claim.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 540px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Forgery Claim</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/HourstoGrossForm.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 580px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">Hours To Gross Form</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/I9_Archive_Form.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 620px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">I-9 Discrepancy</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>


<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/I-9_Scanning_Cover_Sheet_v2.pdf">
<div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 660px;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">I-9 Scanning Cover Sheet v2</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/I9_Scanning_Request.pdf">
<div id="I9ScanningRequestForm" style="top: 700px;width:430px; height:37px;position: absolute;">
<img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
<span class="formTextSpan">I-9 Scanning Request</span>
<div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
</div>
</a>


<div id="FormPreviewPane" style="position: absolute; top: 180px; left: 600px; border: 1px dotted blue; width: 500px; height: 595px; background-color:purple;">
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `+` sign means **immediately after** in the html mark-up.  So unless `#FormPreviewPane` is right after `#I9ScanningRequestForm:hover` - which it isn't in your code - the code won't work as intended. Try removing the `+` and see if that works.

Comment: @Ihazkode I tried changing it from + to ~ and that still did not work. Is there anything else that might do the trick?

Comment: `~` also won't work because `.a ~ .b` means on the same level (shared parent). Just remove the `+` and don't add anything else. Like so:  `#I9ScanningRequestForm:hover  #FormPreviewPane {
 background-color: white;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach.

- First, you are targeting the `:hover` state of the `#I9ScanningRequestForm` element itself, and then attempting to use the `+` selector to target the element that immediately follows it. The problem is, this only works for the next **sibling** element, and `#FormPreviewPane` is a sibling of the **parent** of `#I9ScanningRequestForm` (the `<a>` tag).

  Unfortunately, there's **[no parent selector in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)** (so you can't
  use as `#I9ScanningRequestForm` a 'base'), though assuming the
  structure doesn't change, you can work around this by instead
  targeting the parent `<a>` tag with the pseudo-selector
  **[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)** on the `<a>` tag. If it does change, you can always use **[`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)** instead.
- Second, you're setting the `background-color` of the target element **inline**, which is the highest possible level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**. To override this, you'll need to use the `!important` declaration:

Combining these two points, the colour can be set with the following:

```
a:last-of-type:hover + #FormPreviewPane {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

```css
.opaqueBlock {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-left: 60px;
  width: 360px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #3D5567;
}

.opaqueBlock:hover {
  border: 1px dotted #304A63;
}

.formLinkContainer {
  width: 430px;
  height: 37px;
  position: absolute;
}

.formLinkContainer:hover {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
  opacity: 0.4;
}

a:last-of-type:hover + #FormPreviewPane {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.formTextSpan {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 70px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-family: 'Didact Gothic' !important;
  font-size: 22px !important;
}

.formIcon {
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

img {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact Gothic' rel='stylesheet'>
<div style="background-image: url('/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/WoodBackgroundMedium.jpg') !important; height: 1300px;">
  <br/>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Archiving_Cover_Sheet_Ease.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 180px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Archiving Cover Sheet</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>


  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/ARCHIVING%20SHEET.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 220px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Archiving Sheet</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Data%20Entry%20Feedback.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 260px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Data Entry Feedback Form</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Data_Entry_Comm_Form_10.28.24.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 300px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Data Entry - Commercials</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Data_Entry_Form.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 340px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Data Entry Assistance Request</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/DataPackageRemake.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 380px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Data Package Remake</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/emp_Receivable.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 420px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Employee Receivable Request Form</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Filing_Cover_Sheet_v2.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 460px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Filing Cover Sheet</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/FedEx_UPS_Billing.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 500px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">FedEx/UPS Billing Form</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/Forgery_Claim.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 540px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Forgery Claim</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/HourstoGrossForm.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 580px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">Hours To Gross Form</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/I9_Archive_Form.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 620px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">I-9 Discrepancy</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>


  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/I-9_Scanning_Cover_Sheet_v2.pdf">
    <div class="formLinkContainer" style="top: 660px;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">I-9 Scanning Cover Sheet v2</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/PayrollForms/I9_Scanning_Request.pdf">
    <div id="I9ScanningRequestForm" style="top: 700px;width:430px; height:37px;position: absolute;">
      <img class="formIcon" src="https://epwork.ep.corp/wg/ProdPayroll/Images_Decorative/formIcon.png" />
      <span class="formTextSpan">I-9 Scanning Request</span>
      <div class="opaqueBlock" style=""></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div id="FormPreviewPane" style="position: absolute; top: 180px; left: 600px; border: 1px dotted blue; width: 500px; height: 595px; background-color:purple;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this using some basic JQuery code:

```
$("#FormPreviewPane").on("hover", function() {
  $("#I9ScanningRequestForm").css("background-color", "white");
});
```